# Using filter(lambda, list) in python to clean data

Tags: python, list, filter

I'm web-scraping a website as a project. I am currently clearing the data.
I have a list containing some information/sentences, but some are empty and I wanted to delete them.

My thought was to create a lambda function that identifies null and non-null values ​​to return False or True. Then I would put this function inside the filter() method and pass it to my list. So filter() would apply the function and delete the empty strings from the list.

[image]

Comment: You should change your lambda to `f = lambda s: s != None and len(s) > 0`

Comment: @j1-lee - but there are still empty strings

Answer (score 0):

check `x == ""`

```py
f = lambda x: x is not None and x != ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a lambda here. Use this:

```
lst = ['', 'abc', '', 'def', '', 1, 2, '']

list(filter(None, lst))
```

Output:

```
['abc', 'def', 1, 2]
```

Comment: you're welcome. Just a little advice for the future. If you ask a question, don't use images with code, just add the code you used as text in your question. People can easier reproduce your problem and help. Also vote/accept an answer if you like it. Have a look here for guidance: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that:

- `bool(None)` is `False`
- `bool("")` (empty string) is `False`
- `bool("something")` (non-empty string) is `True`

```py
>>> info = ['', 'abc', '', 'def', '', None]
>>> list(filter(bool, info))
['abc', 'def']
```

Comment: why not `filter(bool, info)`?

Comment: @cards - thanks, I didn't think of that. Updated my answer.